# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] it is lowercased

Tags: java, android

Im getting that error when i try to run my app.

here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms." />
    <activity
        android:name="com.comeze.shekz.meathroads.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When i change the line android:name="com.comeze.shekz.meathroads.MainActivity" to android:name=".MainActivity" i still have the same error.

---

What can i do to fix this error?

Comment: Try removing the meta-data tag and see if it works.

Comment: How did i miss that. Thanks.